# Doubts about migration about Odoo modules from v8 to v10 community - and error

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

consider this method:

```
@api.multi
def _get_loc_req(self): #, cr, uid, context=None
    """Get if a field is required or not by a Localization
    @param uid: Integer value of the user
    """
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    res = True
    ru_brw = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(
        self.cr, uid, uid, context=context)
    rc_obj = self.pool.get('res.company')
    rc_brw = rc_obj.browse(self.cr, uid, ru_brw.company_id.id, context=context)

    if rc_brw.country_id and rc_brw.country_id.code == 'VE' and \
            rc_brw.printer_fiscal:
        res = False
    return res
```

As You can see, I've added `@api.multi` commented `cr, uid, context=None` since multi should take care of these arguments automatically, right?

But for example, if I run this code, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 342, in create
invoice = super(AccountInvoice, self.with_context(mail_create_nolog=True)).create(vals)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 227, in create
thread = super(MailThread, self).create(values)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3778, in create
vals = self._add_missing_default_values(vals)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1618, in _add_missing_default_values
defaults = self.default_get(list(missing_defaults))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1101, in default_get
defaults[name] = field.default(self)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/invoice.py", line 61, in <lambda>
default=lambda s: s._get_loc_req(),
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/invoice.py", line 127, in _get_loc_req
self.cr, uid, uid, context=context)
AttributeError: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'cr'
```

On the method above, I've changed `cr` to `self.cr` as per new api, but no success, same error, and, for example `self.pool.get` shouldn't it be `self.env`? Or can it remain like that?

Generally speaking, what should it look like to be on new API? besides decorator, and `cr` statements?

Another doubt I have, for example, these kind of methods, can be declared like:

```
@api.multi
def my_method(self):
    return
```

But if originally it had, `cr, uid, ids, context` etc, and these arguments are actually INSIDE the method, (like in the method above) should they be replaced? How should it look like?

How can I solve this? And if You can explain these interrogants would be awesome too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method could be written as:

```py
@api.model
def _get_loc_req(self):
    company = self.env.user.company_id
    if (company.country_id and company.country_id.code == 'VE' and
            company.printer_fiscal):
        return False
    return True
```

Regarding your second question - in the new API, there is no need to explicitly pass around `cr,` `uid`, `ids` and context - `cr` (`self.env.cr`), `uid` (`self.env.user`) and `context` (`self.env.context`) are passed to your method via the environment (`self.env`) and the notion of `ids` is replaced with [record sets](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#recordsets). Odoo 10 does not support the old API (pre version 8), so I would recommend spending some time for getting used to the new API: [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#compatibility-between-new-api-and-old-api), [link](https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [link](https://www.slideshare.net/openobject/odoo-from-v7-to-v8-the-new-api), [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/odoo-development-cookbook/9781785883644/ch06s08.html). Also, you might take a look at the code of [official Odoo addons for version 10.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/10.0/addons) - the are all written using the new API.

Comment: That's correct, there is no need to pass curser, uid, etc. anymore anywhere. Every old style method has to be fully rewritten for the new API in Odoo 10, because the old API was removed completely.